# Maximize client window vertically to the half left of screen

Tags: awesome-wm, maximize-window

How to configure a shortcut key in awesome to toggle a client window vertical maximization to the left half of the screen (snap to left)?

[Module awful.placement](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.placement.html) has an example that may help, but there is no mention on how to implement a toggle that would be able to maximize the client or restore it to its prior size and location.

Currently I have the following in `rc.lua`:

```lua
clientkeys = gears.table.join(
    -- ...
    awful.key({ modkey, "Mod1" }, "Left",
        function (c)
            -- Simulate Windows 7 'edge snap' (also called aero snap) feature
            local f = awful.placement.scale + awful.placement.left + awful.placement.maximize_vertically
            f(c.focus, {honor_workarea=true, to_percent = 0.5})
        end ,
        {description = "maximize vertically to the left half of screen", group = "client"})
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `awful.placement.restore`? It seems to do be what you are looking for. However, the documentation says one has to "set[...] the right `context` argument" for this, but does not mention which one that is.

I *think* it should be `scale` since it is the first one in your chain, but I fail to see the logic in calling this chain "`scale`".

To turn that into a toggle, you can "invent" a new client property. Something like this: `if c.my_toggle then print("a") else print("b") end c.my_toggle = not c.my_toggle`. This way, the `my_toggle` property tracks which function you have to call.